# Obtaining correctly formatted client ip using PHP

Tags: php

I have searched for a solution to this both on here and the wider web... to no avail.

After starting to look at how I can obtain a client IP address for users visiting my site, I only ever seem to get a value that is not formatted correctly (like a usual IP address) so am confused.

I was hoping to work this out so I can store IP addresses that repeatedly attempt and fail to log in.

If for example I use something like this:

```
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

...the result is this, even if I try and use a UTF-8 charset:

```
2a00:23c4:9f06:7b00:74e9:d2ca:d5f3:8fe4
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: That looks like an IPV6 address, it there something wrong with it?

Comment: Take a look at this page and, if needed, reformat the question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6   

Comment: Because there are only digits (0-9) and letters (a-f) and some semi-colons(':') in it, it does not matter if it's UTF8 or not....

Comment: OK thanks. I was just expecting it to show this as my device does on my router:
192.186.1.74

Comment: FWIW: Please don't listen to all the people elsewhere on the internet advising you to "just disable IPv6". This is a great opportunity to learn how to use a new tech that we're all going to be using in a few years.

Comment: Mansplaining:  192.186.1.74 is your IP address on your local network (within your house). The IPv6 address above is the address of your router on the Internet.

Comment: Many thanks all. MortimerCat, because my phone was returning a different IPv6 address than my computer I assumed it was not the router's IP at all but device IP... but I am learning!